# DelegateCommand<T> Exception When Binding in DataTemplate

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, prism

I think I've found a bug in the [Prism for Windows Runtime](https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/) library, but I'd like to know if there's a work around or a way to fix the issue without forking the project myself...

I'm trying to display a list of items in an ItemsControl. Each item has a button, which when clicked should execute a command on the parent control's data context and pass the item's ID as the command parameter. Basically, I'm trying to render a list of items and have a delete button for each item. To accomplish this, I'm following this [code sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Command-binding-inside-3cef5eea), which I've so far found as the only clean way to accomplish this feat.

Unfortunately, the `DelegateCommand<T>` class implemented by Prism for Windows Runtime seems to not play well with the XAML binding parser. When everything is hooked up, I receive this exception when the page tries to render:

> Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.Command'. [Line: 61 Position: 49]

I created a new project and simplified my production example to test my theory that this is an issue with `DelegateCommand<T>` (which is needed to allow a parameter to be passed to the delegate method). I implemented two commands, one using `DelegateCommand<T>` and one just using `DelegateCommand`. The one using `DelegateCommand` doesn't cause an exception, but I lose the ability to accept a command parameter which means I can't identify which item was to be deleted.

The XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="TestControl" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.BrokenCommand, ElementName=TestControl}" CommandParameter="1" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The View Model:

```
public DelegateCommand<int> BrokenCommand { get; set; }
public DelegateCommand WorkingCommand { get; set; }

public List<string> MyItems { get { return new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"}; } }

public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    BrokenCommand = new DelegateCommand<int>(BrokenMethod);
    WorkingCommand = new DelegateCommand(WorkingMethod);
}

private void BrokenMethod(int i)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void WorkingMethod()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    BrokenCommand = new DelegateCommand<string> 
    (id => BrokenMethod(Convert.ToInt32((id));
```

I just tested it, and it works if you change your T to string as it comes as a string.

Hopefully somebody can explain why :)

Comment: That results in a compiler error, "Incompatible anonymous function signature". It compiles if I use DelegateCommand<T>, but still produces the original exception.

Comment: Ok, I updated this answer. Please try this, and it needs to be with DelegateCommand<T> as T is your int (id)

Comment: Thanks! This led me down the right track to getting the issue fixed. In the end, all I needed to do was change my property signature to `DelegateCommand<object>`. The working code looks like: `BrokenCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(BrokenMethod);`

Answer (score 1):

I finally made this work after a little inspiration from another answer. I'm not sure why, but the property signature of the delegate command was causing the exception. Changing `DelegateCommand<int>` to `DelegateCommand<object>` makes everything work just fine. Now I can just convert the object to an `int` and go from there. If anyone could offer an explanation as to why this issue happened, that would be excellent!

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="TestControl" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.WorkingCommand, ElementName=TestControl}" CommandParameter="1"></Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

View Model:

```
public DelegateCommand<object> WorkingCommand { get; set; }

public List<string> MyItems { get { return new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"}; } }

public MainPageViewModel()
{
    WorkingCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(WorkingMethod);
}

private void WorkingMethod(object id)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```